# How set ignore_malformed in index level when creating an index through ElasticSearch DSL python wrapper?

Tags: python, python-2.7, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-py

According to [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/ignore-malformed.html), this should be sufficient:

```
"settings": {
    "index.mapping.ignore_malformed": true 
  }
```

But how can I achieve this on python wrapper? My current code looks like this:

```
from elasticsearch_dsl import Index

index = Index('my_index', my_conn)
index.settings(
     number_of_shards=ES_NUMBER_OF_SHARDS,
     number_of_replicas=ES_NUMBER_OF_REPLICAS
)
index.create()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Surprisingly,

```
    index.settings(
        index={'mapping':{'ignore_malformed':True}}
    )
```

Worked perfectly. I'll leave the Q here, since might be useful.

Comment: Yes, `index.settings(**{'index.mapping.ignore_malformed': true})` should also work fine.