# ES Index with python - combine normal Mapping Setting incl. index.mapping.ignore_malformed

Tags: python, elasticsearch, mapping, settings

I need help while trying to add ignore_malformed to my index settings.

I have:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es = Elasticsearch(
  [{'host': 'localhost', 'port': 9200}])

index_name = 'product'

settings = {
"settings": {
    "index.refresh_interval" : "1s",
    "index.mapping.total_fields.limit": 10000,
    "number_of_shards": 1,
    "number_of_replicas": 0
  },
"mappings": {
  "properties": {
        "location": {
          "type": "geo_point"
        }
      },
    "dynamic_templates": [
      {
        "strings_as_keywords": {
          "match_mapping_type": "string",
          "mapping": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}

es.indices.create(index=index_name, body=settings)
```

If I try to add "index.mapping.ignore_malformed": true,
I get:
**NameError: name 'true' is not defined**

With following I can perform this setting but I need both at once while indexing:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
# conntect es
es = Elasticsearch(
  [{'host': 'localhost', 'port': 9200}])
from elasticsearch_dsl import Index
index_name = 'product'
index = Index(index_name, es)
index.settings(
        index={'mapping':{'ignore_malformed':True}}
    )
index.create()
```

Under Edit Settings in Kibana my current index specs are:

```
{
  "index.blocks.read_only_allow_delete": "false",
  "index.priority": "1",
  "index.query.default_field": [
    "*"
  ],
  "index.write.wait_for_active_shards": "1",
  "index.mapping.total_fields.limit": "10000",
  "index.refresh_interval": "1s",
  "index.number_of_replicas": "0"
}
```

How can I combine above mentioned while creating my index to get:

```
{
  "index.blocks.read_only_allow_delete": "false",
  "index.priority": "1",
  "index.query.default_field": [
    "*"
  ],
  "index.write.wait_for_active_shards": "1",
  "index.mapping.total_fields.limit": "10000",
  "index.refresh_interval": "1s",
  "index.mapping.ignore_malformed": "true",
  "index.number_of_replicas": "0"
}
```

Beside:
It is also not possible to add this string by editing in Kibana
Result = Bad Request (wtf why!?)

Reference:
[Empty string in Elasticsearch date field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15924632/empty-string-in-elasticsearch-date-field)

[How set ignore_malformed in index level when creating an index through ElasticSearch DSL python wrapper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43498506/how-set-ignore-malformed-in-index-level-when-creating-an-index-through-elasticse)

Thanks for any help
Regards

Comment: Note the error ```true``` is not defined. However ,```True``` should be. May just have been a typo.

Answer (score 0):

oh yes, typo error...
I reworked the settings, now it works, even on field level :)

```
settings = {
"settings": {
    "index.refresh_interval" : "1s",
    "index.mapping.total_fields.limit": 10000,
    "number_of_shards": 1,
    "number_of_replicas": 0,
    "index.mapping.ignore_malformed": "true"
  },
"mappings": {
  "properties": {
        "location": {
          "type": "geo_point"
        },
        "Date":{
          "type": "date",
          #"ignore_malformed": "true"
        }
      },
    "dynamic_templates": [
      {
        "strings_as_keywords": {
          "match_mapping_type": "string",
          "mapping": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```